# Bash script: check wan ip periodically and act if IP is changed

Tags: bash, gentoo, openrc

I'm new to Bash and I just don't understand how to write a simple script that will do the following.

The script should check what public IP I have, and if IP is changed (in case of ISP1 failure or in case ISP1 will give me another static IP, that happened before), then script should stop OpenVPN server and start OpenVPN client to remote server.

Right now all I could understand and write is this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

myip="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
checkip="$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)"

if [ "$checkip" = "$myip" ]; then
    /etc/init.d/openvpn.server start
    /etc/init.d/openvpn.client stop
else
    /etc/init.d/openvpn server stop
    /etc/init.d/openvpn.client start
fi
```

I can't understand how to loop this script to check IP every 10 seconds and add this to Gentoo to run as a service.

Comment: You can write a bash loop that runs endlessly like this:
`while [ 1 ] ;do  #do stuff here; done`

That being said unless it's imperative that openvpn is being restarted immediately, you may be better off creating a cron job that runs every few minutes.

Comment: 10s seems a bit quick.  DNS changes take hours or days to propagate so reacting within 10s isn't going to prevent you from losing traffic.  Choosing an ISP that actually gives you a static IP address would be more reliable.  Also, to answer your question directly, take a look at [`systemd.timer`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html). This will execute a service based on whatever time conditions you like.  Then make a matching [`service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) to run your script.

Comment: Why do you want to stop/start your OpenVPN client when your IP address changes?

Comment: If my IP will change, then remote clients will not be able to connect to my main server. So in case something happens to ISP1, then backup ISP2 will become active at the router. And after that main server should reconnect to backup server. Backup server will see that main is offline, and will run second openvpn server. Sorry trying to learn english as well, a little bit hard to explain what's is going on in my head :)

Comment: So the OpenVPN server is on a Dynamic IP? Or your OpenVPN client? You use both terms in your question

Comment: No, OpenVPN server is on static IP, but my ISP1 sometimes, for unknown reason, can change static IP anyway. And also ISP1 can simply go offline for some reason. I don't have any other options, besides LTE modem (ISP2) which i use for cases when something happens to ISP1

Comment: Natolio: thanks, while loop is what i need. But how to implement "then else" inside loop is still beyond my understanding. Will try to learn how to do it.

Comment: If your static IP changes then it's not static. Why not just allow dynamic connections for the server? Then you don't need to care about restarting on a change. Just make sure you're using a DDNS tool that can update the domain name pointing to your not-really-static IP address, and have people connect by name

Comment: I understand what you mean, but DDNS will not save me anyway, in case ISP1 will go offline (failure also happens sometimes). So i'm trying to automate this process with my backup remote OpenVPN server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a infinite while loop to constantly check.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
myip="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
while; do
    checkip="$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)"

    if [ "$checkip" = "$myip" ]; then
        /etc/init.d/openvpn.server start
        /etc/init.d/openvpn.client stop
    else
        /etc/init.d/openvpn server stop
        /etc/init.d/openvpn.client start
    fi

    sleep 10
done
```

The `sleep 10` at the end of the loop will cause a 10 second pause before starting the loop again.

I do not know that this is the best way to handle what you are attempting to accomplish, so you may want to consider other avenues.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!